# How can Typescript decorators be used for html labels?

Tags: html, typescript, decorator

I am having a difficult time understanding how to use `Typescript decorators`. I have this code:

```
class Address {
    private street: string;
    private city: string;
    private state: string;
    private zipCode: string;

    @displayName("Street")
    get streetHtml() { return this.street; }

    @displayName("City")
    get cityHtml() { return this.city; }

    @displayName("State")
    get stateHtml()  { return this.state; }

    @displayName("Zip Code")
    get zipCodeHtml() { return this.zipCode; }

    public static map(input: any) {
        let address = new Address();

        address.street = input.street;
        address.city = input.city;
        address.state = input.state;
        address.zipCode = input.zipCode;

        return address;
    }
}

function displayName(name: string) {

    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        let label: HTMLLabelElement = document.createElement('label');

        label.innerHTML = name;

        return label;
    };
}

var address = Address.map({ street: "123 My St", city: "Boise", state: "ID", zipCode: "83709" })

console.log(address.cityHtml);
```

However, the only thing this is doing is returning "Boise". How do I get at the decorator stuff? I did enable `"experimentalDecorators": true`, in my `tsconfig`.

Comment: do you mean the "Boise" value is the only one you see in console? or do you mean in the page? if the one in console. is it not because that is the only thing you print out in console?

Comment: To simplify the problem, I'd recommend you first to try to use decorators on normal functions rather than getters.

Comment: @kucing_terbang he sees "Boise" but he is expecting to see "<label>Boise</label>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @JohnWhite, the getters in your class return a string (that's being inferred by the compiler from the return type), but the decorator you're asking for changes that to return a `HTMLLabelElement`.
This might create difficulties for you in compile time, or end up in runtime errors.

With that being said, to answer your question:
What you return in the decorator isn't the returned value of the accessor, as the [docs say](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#accessor-decorators):

> If the accessor decorator returns a value, it will be used as the
>   Property Descriptor for the member

What you need to do is to change the "Property Descriptor" so that it returns your desired value:

```
function displayName(name: string) {
    return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
        descriptor.get = () => {
            let label: HTMLLabelElement = document.createElement('label');
            label.innerHTML = name;

            return label;
        }
    };
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Address%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20street%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20city%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20state%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20zipCode%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40displayName(%22Street%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20streetHtml()%20%7B%20return%20this.street%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40displayName(%22City%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20cityHtml()%20%7B%20return%20this.city%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40displayName(%22State%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20stateHtml()%20%20%7B%20return%20this.state%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40displayName(%22Zip%20Code%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20zipCodeHtml()%20%7B%20return%20this.zipCode%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20map(input%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20address%20%3D%20new%20Address()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20address.street%20%3D%20input.street%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20address.city%20%3D%20input.city%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20address.state%20%3D%20input.state%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20address.zipCode%20%3D%20input.zipCode%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20address%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20displayName(name%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(target%3A%20any%2C%20propertyKey%3A%20string%2C%20descriptor%3A%20PropertyDescriptor)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20descriptor.get%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20label%3A%20HTMLLabelElement%20%3D%20document.createElement('label')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label.innerHTML%20%3D%20name%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20label%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20address%20%3D%20Address.map(%7B%20street%3A%20%22123%20My%20St%22%2C%20city%3A%20%22Boise%22%2C%20state%3A%20%22ID%22%2C%20zipCode%3A%20%2283709%22%20%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(address.cityHtml)%3B))

---

#### Edit

After posting my answer I noticed that you want to get:

```
<label>Boise</label>
```

But how you tried to implement it (and my answer) returns:

```
<label>City</label>
```

In order to get the desired result we need to change my code a bit:

```
function displayName(name: string) {
    return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
        descriptor.get = function() {
            let label: HTMLLabelElement = document.createElement('label');
            label.innerHTML = this[name.toLowerCase()];

            return label;
        }
    };
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Address%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20street%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20city%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20state%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20zipCode%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40displayName(%22Street%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20streetHtml()%20%7B%20return%20this.street%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40displayName(%22City%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20cityHtml()%20%7B%20return%20this.city%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40displayName(%22State%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20stateHtml()%20%20%7B%20return%20this.state%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40displayName(%22Zip%20Code%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20zipCodeHtml()%20%7B%20return%20this.zipCode%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20map(input%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20address%20%3D%20new%20Address()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20address.street%20%3D%20input.street%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20address.city%20%3D%20input.city%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20address.state%20%3D%20input.state%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20address.zipCode%20%3D%20input.zipCode%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20address%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20displayName(name%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(target%3A%20any%2C%20propertyKey%3A%20string%2C%20descriptor%3A%20PropertyDescriptor)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20descriptor.get%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20label%3A%20HTMLLabelElement%20%3D%20document.createElement('label')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label.innerHTML%20%3D%20this%5Bname.toLowerCase()%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20label%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20address%20%3D%20Address.map(%7B%20street%3A%20%22123%20My%20St%22%2C%20city%3A%20%22Boise%22%2C%20state%3A%20%22ID%22%2C%20zipCode%3A%20%2283709%22%20%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(address.cityHtml)%3B))

Where the changes are:

1. The return function is now a regular anonymous function instead of an arrow function so that the `this` will point to the class instance instead of the window.
2. The label inner html is now `this[name.toLowerCase()]` instead of `name`

Comment: Watch it. The getters in question all return a `string`, which is the expected behavior both during compilation and runtime. However, this decorator implementation will swap the original return type of `string` with `HTMLLabelElement`, which might cause errors that are completely hidden until runtime. At least I, for one, would find it challenging to track down why a variable that is supposedly a string contains an object of another type, especially if the issue is coming from hidden meta-programming.

Comment: @JohnWhite You're completely right, but that's what the OP asked for. Updating my answer with your concern.